# is there a way not to change the screen when loading spinner is spining

Tags: flutter

achieve this?[image]

#in the above picture we can see loading spinner is spinning and when the spinner is activate i dont want to go to back screen but when i press back button of mobile screen it is going back where loading spinner is also still spining in another page. What i am trying to do is when loading spinner is spinning i dont want to change screen even when i press mobile back button which is showing in the picture below at last.

Comment: Do you use any package for the spinner?

Comment: yes for posting data to server i use easyloading package

Comment: Currently its not supported by that package. See https://github.com/0xPool/flutter_easyloading/issues/86

Comment: then to solve problem i will disable android back button interface on some pages

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your top widget with a WillPopScope Widget. This widget allows you to prevent going back when tapping the back button if a certain condition is met. In your case that would be if the loading state is true.

[WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html)

Comment: yes i used willPopScope but in one condition it is not working the condition is :-   onWillPop:()async=>lC.isLoading.value?false:Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("School-List-Screen"),  this lC.isLoading.value is my loading spinner state is in loading but when it is not loading i should be able to do navigation but it is not working can you give some advice

Comment: The onWillPop function always expects a boolean to be returned. In your example you only return false if the loading value is true. You should return true if the loading value is false and remove the call to the navigator as it is not necessary